# YouTube always localizing

Tags: youtube, localization

Every time I log into YouTube my country is set to India. I have to manually change it to Worldwide (all) for world trending videos.

Can anyone tell me how to change it permanently?

Comment: I assume that you're actually _in_ India?

Comment: @AlEverett Ya I'm in India.

Comment: Do you have cookies disabled or otherwise set to clear when you close your browser?

Comment: @phantom42: No not at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fixes localization, but it should at least fix the language setting:

[`http://www.youtube.com/?hl=en&persist_hl=1`](http://www.youtube.com/?hl=en&persist_hl=1)

Also, you can try to remove all YouTube cookies before visiting this URL. It's possible that some cookie keeps referring you back to the Indian version.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/?hl=en&gl=US